# Necessary step in proving closed subsets of compact sets are compact?

Tags: general-topology

In every proof I have seen of the above theorem including this one:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closed_Subspace_of_Compact_Space_is_Compact

The step of removing complement if it is in the cover is included. I was wondering if this step is necessary since every proof includes it yet I cannot see why it would be required?

Comment: Why does the step seem unnecessary?  Where would you prefer to stop the proof?

Comment: The complement isn't in the original open cover $\mathcal{U}$, so we remove it so that we're using a finite subcover of the original open cover.

Comment: Ahh that all makes sense now, thankyou.

Comment: See Q# 2302814 which is the same Q about the same theorem, applied to metric spaces, but the proof and the A apply to all for  spaces.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the proof you've linked: our goal is to show that $\mathcal U$ has a finite subcover.  Note that $\mathcal V$, as it is defined, is not necessarily a subcover of $\mathcal U$, hence the need for us to take out $(T\setminus C)$.

Comment: It is my understanding that a cover of $A$ is a collection of sets $U$ such that $A$ is contained in the union, and a subcover is a subcollection of $U$ that still covers $A$. 

In the linked proof since $C \subset \mathcal V \cup \{ T \setminus C \}$ and this is finite it is not required that one removes $\{ T \setminus C \}$ from the cover?

Comment: Have just read Michael Burr's comment, it all makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with how you define a subspace topology, then to say that a subspace $C$ of $T$ is compact means that with any open subsets in $T$ that 'cover' $C$ you can find a finite number of them that do the job. Of course if $C$ in closed its complement is open and you can throw that in with the initial cover (which without other assumptions sounds like a dumb thing to do) - it won't change a thing in terms of finite subcovers for $C$ since you are not really adding anything (see below.)

When $T$ is also compact you now have and open cover of $T$, and you can get a finite subcover of both $T$ and $C$ at the same time.

To answer your question, there is **NO REASON TO THROW OUT THAT OPEN SET**. It happens to be the empty open set (that is what it corresponds to in the subspace $C$)  but not to worry. If you have a finite cover of any space, throwing in the empty set as part of the cover does not change a thing. And it doesn't help at all in finding a finite subcover.

In a proof, one could say then are going to add the empty set to the initial cover, expressed as the complement of $C$ in $T$.

So, a proof could handle it in three way:

1. not mention this hair splitting stuff at all
2. take the set out at the end
3. or change the cover at the start